# list linking to a polygon (building) in google maps from JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, polygons

I cobbled together a campus map for our local college loading buildings outlines from a json file. The building themselves are clickable with info windows. Now I am trying to get a side nav with a list of the buildings to be able to click on it and load the correct building info/outline. Can you point me in the right direction? I've seen examples of this using the markers/infowindows and side lists but never with a clickable polygons.

```
 var $ul = $('#buildings');
 function myList() {
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    $.getJSON('campus1.json', function(data){
    $.each(data.places, function(i, item){ 
        $ul.append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>');
      })

    });
}
//create building list
myList();

var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    //zoom: 4,
    //center: {lat: -28, lng: 137.883}
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: 48.490802, lng: -123.416497},
    mapTypeControlOptions:{
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
                }
  });

// array of styles
        var styles = [
              {
                "featureType": "poi.school",
                "elementType": "labels",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "poi.business",
                "elementType": "labels",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "elementType": "labels.text",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              },{
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
              }
            ];
    // new styledMapType object, passing the array of styles and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"});
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('campus4.json');

  // [START snippet]
  // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
  // is set to true.
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = 'gray';
    if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
      color = feature.getProperty('color');
    }
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
  });

  // When the user clicks, creates building info box.
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    //event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
    var title = event.feature.getProperty("title");
    var abrev  = event.feature.getProperty("abrevs");
    var desc   = event.feature.getProperty("desc2");
    var image  = event.feature.getProperty("picture");
    var ids    = event.feature.getProperty("id");
    infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:450px; text-align: center;'><h3 id='"+ids+"'>"+title+"</h3><p><strong>Abrev:</strong> " +abrev+ "</p><img src=\"" +image+ "\" /><p>" +desc+ "</p></div>");
    //infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
    if (event){
        point = event.latLng;
    }
    infowindow.setPosition(point);
    //infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)});
    infowindow.open(map);
  });

  // When the user hovers, tempt them to click by outlining the Buildings.
  // Call revertStyle() to remove all overrides. This will use the style rules
  // defined in the function passed to setStyle()
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        map.data.revertStyle();
        map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 8});
  });//mouse over listener

  map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
  });//mouse over listener
  // [END snippet]
} <!-- end of initialize function -->

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

currently this code loads 2 different json files of the same data, although slightly different formatting. Is it possible to link to polygon object and activate it with the google maps api?

sorry forgot to give example of json files i am using. currently using A as main one but pulling for B for list, working draft, eventually going to pull from one file ideally. Reason I used json file was to make it easy for non-IT people to edit etc, who maintain it at the college. This is just sample data thrown in, not real coordinates, and not really a javascript experienced.

**A Example**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{ {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Carpentry Classroom",
            "abrevs": "ICC",
            "letter": "Carpentry Classroom",
            "id": "icc",
            "desc2": "need info",
            "picture": "",
            "description": "the second letter o"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[-120.418600913561,
            4649213741465642],
            [-120.4184934907869,
            46.49215116618643],
            [-120.4185235814502,
            46.49224517610932],
            [-120.4186311820468,
            46.49223142763702],
            [-120.418600913561,
            46.49213741465642]]]
        }
    }
    }]
}
```

**B Example**

```
{
    "places" : [{
            "title" : "Campus Centre",
            "abrev" : "Campus Centre",
            "description" : "description tex.",
            "image": "http://example.com/campus-centre.jpg",
            "alt": "CampusCentre",
            "lat" : 46.491031,
            "lng" : -120.418565
        }
]}
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you have so far.  And the HTML/CSS that defines where the side bar will go.

Comment: [One example (using KML for polygons rather than GeoJSON)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_us_states_kml_test.html)

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot in order to understand the functionality you are trying to implement!

Comment: My project originally started from this template, [UofT template](http://communications.utk.edu/resources/web/map/) similar setup. But I wanted to use polygons(building outlines) instead of markers.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, I used the kml example.